# Среда выполнения С#

Tags: c#

Есть desktop приложение на Java. Подумываю перенести его на С#, исходя из того что большинство пользователей будет на Windows. Как я понимаю среда исполнения называется .NET Framework. На большинстве Windows она предустановленна. Собственно сам вопрос: правильно ли я всё понял и какая будет разница между Windows 7/8/10?

Comment: Разница в том, что под .NET есть вменяемый UI-фреймворк, в отличие от Java.

Comment: А с меньшинством что делать будете? Поддерживать две версии одновременно?

Comment: @Vlad предлагать устанавливать им .NET Framework или таскать с установочными

Comment: @RodGers можете попробовать копнуть под Mono, вроде как позиционирует себя "кросплатформенным .NET", но лично я с ним еще не разбирался.

Comment: @XelaNimed [пожалуйста, не отправляйте в поиск](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987)

Comment: Я не в поиск отправил, а ссылку дал, какая будет разница между версиями .Net и операционными системами.

Comment: @RodGers, framework на Linux ставить?

Comment: @Vlad, а что не так?

Comment: @Grundy, так он же туда не ставится без плясок с бубном. Если речь идет именно о большом и свежем .Net Framework (например, 4.5).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По терминологии:

- C# - язык программирования
- .NET Framework - платформа
- Среда исполнения у .NET приложений - CLR

По версиям .NET Framework Windows 7-10 поддерживают .NET 2.0 вплоть до .NET 4.6.2.

Предустановленные версии .NET Framework ([тыц](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx)):

- Windows 7  - .NET 3.5
- Windows 8  - .NET 4.5
- Windows 10 - .NET 4.6

Comment: Не, не совсем верно. Последняя версия - 4.7 и она является предустановленной начиная с Windows 10 Creators Update, на более ранних версиях Win10 вы правильно указали — предустановлена .NET 4.6.

Comment: Ну и нужно добавить, что если есть ПК с XP, то максимальная версия, которую можно использовать - `4.0`